# Given a permutation, how to calculate the number of nonidentity odd cycles of it?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

$\sigma$ is a permutation on $n$ points and it can be written as a product of nonidentity cycles, how to calculate the number of odd nonidentity cycles in this product?

This number is congruent to $n\; (\mod\;2)$.

Comment: What does $i$ refer to?

Comment: I have made a mistake, it should be $n$.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Every permutation can be written as the product of disjoint cycles in an essentially unique way.  Do you have a specific permutation $\sigma$ in mind, or are you looking for some kind of general statement?  If the latter, what would be the answer you're looking for in the case $n=3?$